# How can I "count from the back" in python lists?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.5

Say I have a list
`l = ['h','e','l','l','o']`
I want to be able to take the last two items and use them, but I don't know how long the list
is(It's user input). So can't do `l[3:]` because what if the list is seven(or any number) items long instead of five?

How can I count from the back of the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
print l[-2:]
```

Negative numbers count from the end.

```
>>> l = ['h','e','l','l','o']
>>> print l[-2:]
['l', 'o']
>>> print l[-5:]
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> print l[-6:]
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

There you go , this should give you a good idea

```
  l = ['h','e','l','l','o']
    print l[2:]
    #['l', 'l', 'o']
    print l[:2]
    #['h', 'e']
    print l[:-2]
    #['h', 'e', 'l']
    print l[-2:]
    #['l', 'o']
```

In your case, as someone has already suggested you can use, the bellow to print last two items in the list

```
print l[-2:]
```

But if you insist accesing the list from the start ,while not knowing what would be lenth of the list , you can use the following to print

```
 l[len(l)-2:]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a list `a`:

```
>>> a  = ['1','2','3','4']
```

You can reference the 3rd element from the end with `-3`.

```
>>> a[-3]
'2'
```

Specify a range from 3rd last to before the 2nd last (yes, that's just one.):

```
>>> a[-3:-2]
['2']
```

Specify a range from 3rd last to before the last:

```
>>> a[-3:-1]
['2', '3']
```

And specify a range from the 3rd last to after the last:

```
>>> a[-3:5]
['2', '3', '4']
```

It's kind of fun that way, is Python.